# Why are formulas not propagating in null fields?

Tags: qliksense

I'm trying to change the value of nulls to something else that can be used to filter. This data comes from a QVD file. The field that contains nulls, contains nulls due to no action taken on those items ( they will eventually change to something else once an action has been taken).  I found [this link](https://community.qlik.com/t5/QlikView-Documents/NULL-handling-in-QlikView/ta-p/1484472?attachment-id=135541)  which was very informative but i tried multiple solutions from the document to no avail.

What i don't quite understand is that whenever i make a new field (in the script or as an expression) the formula does not propagate in the records that are null, it shows " - ".  For instance, the expression isNull(ActionTaken) will return false in a field that that not null, but only " - " in fields that are null.  If i export the table to Excel, the " - " is exported, i copy this cell to a text analyzer i  the UTF-8 encoded is \x2D\x0A\x0A, i'm not sure if that's an artifact of the export process.

I also tried using the [NullAsValue](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/April2020/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/ScriptRegularStatements/NullAsValue.htm) statement but no luck.  Using a combination of Len & Trim = 0 will return the same result as above.  This is only one table, no other tables are involved.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar case few years ago where the field looked empty but actually it was filled with a character which just looked empty. Trimming the field also didnt worked as expected in this case, because the character code was different

What I can suggest you is to check if the character number, returned for the empty value, is actually an empty string. You can use the [ord](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/April2020/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/StringFunctions/Ord.htm) to check the character number for the empty values. Once you have the number then you can use this number to replace it with whatever you want (for example empty string)